# Change time format from number like 600 to 06:00:00

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, A and B, and two sheets, 1 and 2, in both the workbooks.I need to compare and find the match based on time.In workbook B in sheet 1 I have hh:mm:ss 24 hrs time format.But in workbook A I have the time from and to in number format like 600 and 800 etc. I have changed the time format in workbook 1 to hh:mm:ss but the problem I am getting after running for the first time is that the time has changed to 06:00:00 and again in the second run it is changed to 00:00:00.

```
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iHours As Integer
    Dim iMins As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rn As Range

    lrow = Sot.Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sot.Activate
    Set rCell = Sot.Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(lrow, 5))

    For Each rn In rCell
        If IsNumeric(rn.Value) And Len(rn.Value) > 0 Then
            iHours = rn.Value \ 100
            iMins = rn.Value Mod 100
            rn.Value = (iHours + iMins / 60) / 24
            rn.NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        End If
    Next

    For i = 5 To eRowplan
        Time_from = Sotplan.Range("D" & i).Value
        Time_To = Sotplan.Range("E" & i).Value
        Time_from = TimeSerial(Hour(Time_from), Minute(Time_from), 
        Second(Time_from))
        Time_To = TimeSerial(Hour(Time_To), Minute(Time_To), Second(Time_To))
        If B_Time > "24:00" Then B_Time = "23:59"
        B_Time = TimeSerial(Hour(B_Time), Minute(B_Time), Second(B_Time))
```

I tried with above codes

Comment: What are 600 and 800? seconds? minutes? hours?

Comment: that 600 is 06:00:00 hh:mm:ss

Comment: If 600 means 06:00:00 I guess then 800 means 08:00:00. In that case, just divide value by 100 and then again 24. Something like `600/100/24` will return a decimal value equivalent to `06:00:00` if yoy apply time format. And `800/100/24` will return `08:00:00`

Comment: How would you represent seconds?  Would `8hrs 10 sec` be `80010` or would it be `800.1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following if you want a `VBA` solution for e.g. 600 = 600 minutes

```
Dim c

For Each c In Selection
    c.Value2 = c / (24 * 60)
    c.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
Next c
```

Or just use `= A1 / (24 * 60)` and format as `Time`

---

***Update after comments***

For 600 = 06:00:00 you can use the following

```
Dim c, tmpTime As Variant

For Each c In Selection
    ' Test if number
    If IsNumeric(c.Value2) Then
        ' Split into character array, the Len(c.Value2) limits the size of the array otherwise
        ' an additional empty element is created
        tmpTime = Split(StrConv(c.Value2, vbUnicode), Chr$(0), Len(c.Value2))
        ' Write results back and format
        With c.Offset(0, 1)
            .Value2 = Join(tmpTime, ":")
            .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        End With
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: But wouldn't `600/1440` equate to `10` hours then?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes it would - I was reading the question as 600 being the number of minutes.

Comment: The difficult part with all of this is that we have been provided with incomplete data, as to how times are represented in the non-standard format.  eg. `1200` ?= 12 hrs.  And how are seconds represented?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes agreed -this has limitations